# How to concatenate first_name and last_name in $request filter using Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I have this code I use to filter by first_name or last_name

Controller

```
if(isset($request->first_name) || isset($request->last_name))
{
    $employees=$employees
            ->where('first_name','like','%'.$request->first_name.'%')
            ->orWhere('last_name','like','%'.$request->last_name.'%');
            $render['first_name']=$request->first_name;
    $render['last_name']=$request->last_name;
}
```

View

```
{{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    
   <div form-group class="col-sm-3">
        {{Form::label('first_name', 'Employee Name')}}
        {{ Form::text('first_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Staff Name']) }}             
    </div>                
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <br>
        {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}

    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

I want to filter using first_name or last_name. But I want to concatenate the two, so that whichever one the user type will do the searching

Instead of having it separately for first_name and last_name. How do I concatenate to have a singular one joining first_name and last_name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Query Builders [when](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses) function, so that when first name is present it will match it to first or last, and when last name is present it will match it to first or last.

```
$name = preg_replace('/([\s])+/', ' ', $request->name);
$name = explode(' ', $name);

if (count($name) > 3) {
   // This would be an error handle in validation
   // ie. First Middle Last
}

$first = array_shift($name);
$first = strtoupper($last);

$last = array_shift($last);
$last = $last ? strtoupper($last) : null;

$employees = $employees
    ->when($first, function ($query, $first) {
        return $query->whereRaw("UPPER(first_name) LIKE %$first%")
                     ->orWhereRaw("UPPER(last_name) LIKE %$first%");
    })
    ->when($last, function ($query, $last) {
        return $query->whereRaw("UPPER(last_name) LIKE %$last%")
                     ->orWhereRaw("UPPER(first_name) LIKE %$last%");
    });
```

To add a last_name input:

```
{{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    
    <div form-group class="col-sm-3">
        {{Form::label('name', 'Employee Name')}}
        {{ Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Employee Name']) }}  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <br>
        {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}

    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Kurtfriars - How do I now treat it at the view blade. This is what I have              {{ Form::text('first_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Staff Name']) }}                             It is also well detailed in the code above

Comment: Do you mean you also want to add a last_name input to your form?

Comment: Yes. To also concatenate first_name and last_name as one for the filter in the input form. As done in the controller

Comment: Added a last name input, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I mean to add first name and last name together as one input for the filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217330/discussion-between-kurt-friars-and-mikefolu).

Comment: The page is not loading until when I commented this
$first = array_shift($name);
$first = strtoupper($last);

$last = array_shift($last);
$last = $last ? strtoupper($last) : null;

Comment: I got this error:     #message: "Undefined variable: last"
 and it refers to this line   $first = strtoupper($last);